# Нужна ли запятая перед «как» в предложении?

Tags: запятые, обороты-с-как

В предложении «Я воспринимаю работу как часть своей жизни» нужна запятая перед «как»? Склоняюсь, что да. Не в качестве части своей жизни ведь... И можно задать вопрос: «Воспринимаю работу как? Как часть жизни».

Answer (score 2):

Нееет. Вам хочется сравнения, а ничего ни с чем не сравнивается.

Читать надо так: «Я воспринимаю (считаю) работу частью своей жизни». Замена/проверка творительным падежом.

---

[Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК в пяти случаях:](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

> (Наш). Если оборот с союзом КАК в предложении выступает в роли
> обстоятельства образа действия, например: *Тропинка извивалась как
> змея*. В таких случаях оборот с КАК можно заменить наречием
> (ПО-ЗМЕИНОМУ) или существительным в творительном падеже (ЗМЕЕЙ).

Answer (score 1):

Запятую не ставят, так как это все дуплексив (суперсказуемое).
Есть проблемы даже с синтаксическим разбором такого предложения

```
Работу я воспринимаю частью жизни.
```

В ряде источников говорится, что это

> в) Дуплексив, относящийся к сказуемому и дополнению. Напр.: Родители
> привезли меня в этот город трёхлетним мальчиком.

и

> Дуплексивы чаще всего выражаются: 7. Существительным со словом как.

Там же указываются примеры с запятой при дуплексивах, типа:

```
Работу я воспринимаю очень серьёзно, частью жизни.
```

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. Это всё является сказуемым, а запятые ставятся между членами предложения, но не внутри них.